# How to Compare between Objects property's then sort using ( sortusingselector:@selector)?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to write a simple function == " compareGPA" that compares between the GPA of two students , then sorting them in descending order by using selector as that : [array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareGPA:)];

I've tried to write the function in 2 different ways , but nothing works  ,

**First way :**

```
+(NSComparisonResult) compareGPA: (Student *) OtherStudent{ 

Student *tmp =[Student new];

if ([OtherStudent getGpa] < [tmp getGpa]){

return (NSComparisonResult) tmp;

}

if([tmp getGpa] < [OtherStudent getGpa])

{ return (NSComparisonResult) OtherStudent; }


}
```

**2nd way :**

```
+(NSComparisonResult) compareGPA: (Student *) OtherStudent{


NSComparisonResult res;


res = [[self getGpa] compare: [OtherStudent getGpa]];

return res;

Switch (res)
{

case NSOrderedAscending:

return NSOrderedDescending;

break;

case NSOrderedDescending:

return NSOrderedAscending;

break;

default:

return NSOrderedSame;

break;

}

}
```

Output : Nothing

Any suggestions ??

Comment: what class is getGpa returning? int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make your caparison method

```
+(NSComparisonResult) compareGPA: (Student *) OtherStudent
```

an instance method (not a class method, + becomes -), so that it compares the receiver's GPA with OtherStudent's GPA), like this

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compareGPA: (Student *) OtherStudent {

     // if GPA is a float int double ...
     if ([OtherStudent getGpa] == [self getGpa] 
         return NSOrderedSame;
     if ([OtherStudent getGpa] < [self getGpa]){
         return NSOrderedAscending;
     return NSOrderedDescending;

     // if GPA is an object which responds to the compare: message
     return [[self getGPA] compare:[OtherStudent getGPA]]

}
```

Then sort your array of Student objects using selector `@selector(compareGPA:)`

Comment: I did the above steps , program runs without any erros or warnings but Nothing appears on the console window , I've already created the array and added the objects and called : [array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareGPA:)]; , what do you think to be missing ??

Answer (score 5):

As you're using `compare:` I have to assume that `getGPA` returns an `NSNumber`, in which case all you'd need would be this:

```
NSArray *students = ...;
NSArray *sortedStudents = [students sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"getGPa" ascending:NO]]];
```

If `getGPA` however was to return some primitice C type (such as `float` in your case), then you could do it this way:

```
NSArray *students = ...;
NSArray *sortedStudents = [students sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Studen *student1, Studen *student2) {
    float student1GPA = [student1 getGPA];
    float student2GPA = [student2 getGPA];
    if (student1GPA < student2GPA) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (student1GPA > student2GPA) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

If if you need the `compareGPA:` elsewhere, too:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareGPA:(Studen *otherStudent) {
    float student1GPA = [self getGPA];
    float student2GPA = [otherStudent getGPA];
    if (student1GPA < student2GPA) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (student1GPA > student2GPA) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```